# How can I get this data in a single row

Tags: oracle

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(X,'MON'),TO_CHAR(X,'DD')
FROM
(SELECT CASE WHEN TO_CHAR(TO_DATE('01-MAY-2015')+(ROWNUM-1),'DY') = 'FRI' THEN<br>
TO_DATE('01-MAY-15')+(ROWNUM-1) ELSE NULL END AS X FROM all_objects<br>
WHERE ROWNUM < (select (to_date ('01-MAY-16') - to_date('01-MAY-15')+1) <br>
  from dual)) 
WHERE X IS NOT NULL;
```

I want to display the the date of friday on every week of the month for a give year, starting from the give date.

suppoise if I give the start date as 01-MAR-2015 TO 29-FEB-2016
Ten I should get like

mar mar mar mar apr apr apr apr may............feb feb
06      13      20    27  3  10------------------------- 19 26

I am getting them in columns. How can i get them in row.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You may need something like this:

```
with test(start_date) as
    (select to_date('15022016', 'ddmmyyyy') from dual) /* your start date */
select listagg(to_char(date_, 'dd/mm/yyyy'), ', ')
        within group(order by date_) /* concatenation of dates */
from (
        select start_date + level -1 date_ /* to generate dates */
        from test
        connect by start_date + level -1  <= add_months(start_date, 12) /* to keep dates in one year from the starting date */
     )
where to_char(date_, 'd') = 5 /* check if friday, the 5th day of week */
```

I put some comments in the code to give a minimum explanation af the different parts.